# PHP will not write file to directory via command prompt executed script but will write when executed in browser

Tags: php, windows, command, prompt

I will execute this command in Command Prompt

```
php C:\xampp\htdocs\dl.php
```

These are the properties of my htdocs directory:

[image]

However, under the sharing tab, I have write permissions under all users:

[image]

I've restarted apache after each permission modification with no success.
How do I fix this?

My PHP script downloads an XML file via an API and writes the XML file into the root directory of the server. When I execute www.mydomain.com/dl.php, the downloaded XML is written into the root directory; however, when I execute the PHP file (dl.php) via the command prompt, it will not write the downloaded file into the root directory.

PHP file:

```
$today = date("F j, Y").".xml";
$ch = curl_init ("");

$fp = fopen("ipod_car_connectors2.xml", "w");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: What is the problem in the first place? What doesn't work that makes you try this?

Comment: Possibly a current working directory problem. Are you specifying full path inside your code? Would be good to see the code as well.

Comment: @djdy see edit, I updated with code

Comment: add `ini_set('display_errors', 'on');` and `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to the top and tell us what you see from the command line.

Comment: Warning: curl_setopt(); supplied argument is not a valid File-Handle resource in C:\xampp\htdocs\dl.php on line 16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  The solution was to escape slashes
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing it to:

`$fp = fopen("c:\xampp\htdocs\ipod_car_connectors2.xml", "w");`